# If regulators join after a transaction has taken place, can they be informed of the transaction?

Tags: corda

Let's assume we have a network where certain transactions have taken place and at a certain later point, a regulator steps in as an observer node. Is there a way to send the previous transaction (which already took place) to the regulator?

Answer (score 2):

You may also use SendStateAndRefFlow, which will reduce the amount of migration work involved in supporting SGX ledger encryption in future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is `SendTransactionFlow` available as part of the Corda platform.

You provide transaction hash and the party to send the transaction to (as arguments to SendTransactionFlow).

The only trick is, you need to ensure you use ALL_VISIBLE for the record level as the regulator will not be a participant in the states.

For more information check out these [docs](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-observer-nodes.html)